# iPad app where possible draw, save for reuse and drop 'objects' on canvas for prototyping and to make mockup

Tags: ipad, ios, software-recommendation, drawing

For prototyping / mockup needs, I want an iPad app where it's possible to draw, save and drop 'templates' on a canvas.
Something similar to [balsamiq mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups), where there is a collection of components that can be placed on canvas, but with the ability to create my own components by drawing and saving for later reuse.

Answer (score 0):

The best app that comes to mind is Sketchbook Pro for the iPad. It's like a simplified version of Photoshop where it has brushes and a lot of features that are at the mercy of your fingertips. I have it, and it's great for prototyping / making concept art real quick.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sketchbook-pro-for-ipad/id364253478?mt=8

I don't know what you mean by saving and dropping templates onto a canvas, but hopefully this link will steer you in the right direction.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/omnigraffle/id363225984?mt=8 Maybe this app will suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [App Cooker](http://www.appcooker.com/)? It lets you create your own components for your mockup. (However, it is not clear from their webpage whether user-created content is available for *every* mockup, or if it is only present in the project where you created it.)